# my 'smallest method gives different results if order of when the words/numbers are added is changed

Tags: java, compareto

So basically my code is doing what the question says. In the way the code is laid out now it gives the correct results, but when I change the order of the .add pieces of code it gives different results each time. I feel the `compareTo` method is fine, but am i missing something? I'm trying to get the smallest result.

Thanks in advance.

```
package lists;

import java.util.*;

public class Lab4 {
    public static <T extends Comparable> int smallest(List<T> l) {
        if (l.size() == 0) 
            return -1;
        else {
            Iterator<T> it = l.iterator();
            T smallestSoFar = it.next();
            T temp;

            int smallestPos = 0;
            int i = 0; //used to indicate position in list of next item
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                temp = it.next();

                if (temp.compareTo(smallestSoFar) > 0) {
                    smallestSoFar = temp;
                    smallestPos++;
                }
                i++;
            }

            return smallestPos;
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable> void deleteSmallest(List<T> l) { // for exercise 3
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<String> vec1 = new Vector<String>();
        vec1.add("Hello");
        vec1.add("xxxx");
        vec1.add("world");
        vec1.add("aardvark");

        int smallPos = smallest(vec1);
        if (smallPos != -1)
            System.out.println("smallest entry is " + vec1.elementAt(smallPos) + " at position " + smallPos);
        Vector<Integer> vec2 = new Vector<Integer>();

        vec2.add(new Integer(47));
        vec2.add(new Integer(247));
        vec2.add(new Integer(17));
        vec2.add(new Integer(399));

        smallPos = smallest(vec2);
        if (smallPos != -1)
            System.out.println("smallest entry is " + vec2.elementAt(smallPos) + " at position " + smallPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison test is the wrong way around. Currently you're picking the largest value.

```
if (temp.compareTo(smallestSoFar) > 0) {
```

Should be

```
if (temp.compareTo(smallestSoFar) < 0) {
```

Also, `smallestPos++;`should be `smallestPos=i;`

Currently you're returning a count of the number of times the "smallest" value changed.

Answer (score 2):

With java8 you can make your `smallest()` method more compact:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int smallest( List<T> list ){
    return list.stream()               // get Stream<T> from list
        .sorted(Comparable::compareTo) // Stream<T> is now sorted
        .mapToInt(list::indexOf)       // maps Stream<T> to an IntStream consisting of indices
        .findFirst()                   // find the first value (the smallest)
        .orElse(-1);                   // if nothing found, hence list was empty, then return -1
}
```

and when i tested it with my function there were no inconsistencies